# javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Exception creating bean of class After convert my project into gradle project

Tags: gradle, struts

I created a simple login web app using `struts 1.3.` and it works fine. Then I needed to convert that project into `gradle project` ,for that I followed some tutorials and I ran it with `tomcat`. It shows the following error.

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Exception creating bean of class
```

Comment: Please see the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page. There's nothing here anyone can use to help.

Comment: got it.Thank you .